# How do I get data from this object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, oauth

Here's the object that's returned. I ultimately need to get two things: `@token` and `@expires_at`. How would I get them from this?

```
@my_object = access_token(params[:provider])
```

Then outputs:

```
#<OAuth2::AccessToken:0x007fd03df75db8 
   @client=#<OAuth2::Client:0x007fd035040ad0 
      @id="123xyz", 
      @secret="xyz123", 
      @site="https://graph.facebook.com", 
      @options={
         :authorize_url=>"/oauth/authorize", 
         :token_url=>"oauth/access_token", 
         :token_method=>:post, 
         :connection_opts=>{
            :ssl=>{
               :ca_file=>"ca-bundle.crt"
            }
         }, 
         :connection_build=>nil, 
         :max_redirects=>5, 
         :raise_errors=>true, 
         :mode=>:query, 
         :param_name=>"access_token", 
         :parse=>:query
      }, 
      @auth_code=#<OAuth2::Strategy::AuthCode:0x007fd035040c88 
         @client=#<OAuth2::Client:0x007fd035040ad0 ...>>, 
         @connection=#<Faraday::Connection:0x007fd037aec978 
            @headers={"User-Agent"=>"Faraday v0.8.7"}, 
            @params={}, 
            @options={}, 
            @ssl={:ca_file=>"ca-bundle.crt"}, 
            @parallel_manager=nil, 
            @default_parallel_manager=nil, 
            @builder=#<Faraday::Builder:0x007fd037aeca68 
               @handlers=[Faraday::Request::UrlEncoded, Faraday::Adapter::NetHttp]>, 
               @url_prefix=#<URI::HTTPS:0x007fd037aecf90 URL:https://graph.facebook.com/>, 
                  @proxy=nil, 
                  @app=#<Faraday::Request::UrlEncoded:0x007fd037aeb3c0 
                     @app=#<Faraday::Adapter::NetHttp:0x007fd037aeb370 
                        @app=#<Proc:0x007fd037aeb2a8@/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/connection.rb:87 (lambda)>>>>>, 
                        @token="token_123", 
                        @refresh_token=nil, 
                        @expires_in=5149095, 
                        @expires_at=1373851292, 
                        @options={
                           :mode=>:query, 
                           :header_format=>"Bearer %s", 
                           :param_name=>"access_token"
                        }, 
                        @params={:token_url=>"oauth/access_token"}>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit** it should actually be

```
@my_object.token
```

and

```
@my_object.expires_at
```

I found out by re-indenting your object dump like this:

```
#<OAuth2::AccessToken:0x007fd03df75db8 
  @client=#<OAuth2::Client:0x007fd035040ad0 
    @id="123xyz", 
    @secret="xyz123", 
    @site="https://graph.facebook.com", 
    @options={
      :authorize_url=>"/oauth/authorize", 
      :token_url=>"oauth/access_token", 
      :token_method=>:post, 
      :connection_opts=>{
        :ssl=>{
          :ca_file=>"ca-bundle.crt"
        }
      }, 
      :connection_build=>nil, 
      :max_redirects=>5, 
      :raise_errors=>true, 
      :mode=>:query, 
      :param_name=>"access_token", 
      :parse=>:query
    }, 
    @auth_code=#<OAuth2::Strategy::AuthCode:0x007fd035040c88 
      @client=#<OAuth2::Client:0x007fd035040ad0 ...>
    >, 
    @connection=#<Faraday::Connection:0x007fd037aec978 
      @headers={"User-Agent"=>"Faraday v0.8.7"}, 
      @params={}, 
      @options={}, 
      @ssl={:ca_file=>"ca-bundle.crt"}, 
      @parallel_manager=nil, 
      @default_parallel_manager=nil, 
      @builder=#<Faraday::Builder:0x007fd037aeca68 
        @handlers=[Faraday::Request::UrlEncoded, Faraday::Adapter::NetHttp]
      >, 
      @url_prefix=#<URI::HTTPS:0x007fd037aecf90 URL:https://graph.facebook.com/>, 
      @proxy=nil, 
      @app=#<Faraday::Request::UrlEncoded:0x007fd037aeb3c0 
        @app=#<Faraday::Adapter::NetHttp:0x007fd037aeb370 
          @app=#<Proc:0x007fd037aeb2a8@/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/connection.rb:87 (lambda)>
        >
      >
    >
  >, 
  @token="token_123", 
  @refresh_token=nil, 
  @expires_in=5149095, 
  @expires_at=1373851292, 
  @options={
    :mode=>:query, 
    :header_format=>"Bearer %s", 
    :param_name=>"access_token"
  }, 
  @params={:token_url=>"oauth/access_token"}
>
```

Comment: Because an object have attributes don't imply in having accessors. Your question gets on the right end by the wrong way.

Comment: You're right, but why would SomeObject.to_s include instance vars that are not accessible?

Comment: I don't know, I'm not used to declare `to_s` in my objects, and since this is the default behavior it is not reliable. However it is ok to avoid looking at the documentation by guessing that it is readable, I also do this. Yet it is not a secure way when you have doubts like the OP.

Comment: Instance variables are *never* accessible and they are *always* included in the default pretty print.

Comment: As i said you're both right, i found the solution by accident, going the wrong path. This is why i upvoted @grotori's answer.

Comment: Instance variables are always accessible, as long as they exist.  They are accessible through ObjectSpace.  It is just a matter of accessing them.  They may just not have an attr_* or hand written accessor.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this](http://rdoc.info/github/intridea/oauth2/OAuth2/AccessToken) you should be able to access them by:

```
@my_object.token
@my_object.expires_at
```

Comment: Your approach is the better one, +1

Answer (score 1):

As `@grotori` pointed out, you should be looking at [the documentation](http://rdoc.info/github/intridea/oauth2/OAuth2/AccessToken) instead of the object to define how to access the object attributes.

Note that an instance variable from an object is usually printed along with the object, but this doesn't mean that it is in the class expected interface.

For example:

```
class A
  def initialize
    @foo = 'bar'
  end
end
 => nil 

# Have the @foo attribute
A.new
 => <A:0xa232904 @foo="bar">

# Can't access it
p A.new.foo
NoMethodError: undefined method `foo' for #<A:0xa230280 @foo="bar">
```

Comment: Not having accessors doesn't mean you can't get to them.  `A.new.instance_variable_get(:@foo)`  The reason you couldn't get to it is because your method called initalize was never called.  I think you must have meant `initialize` rather than initilize, so you got `nil`.

Comment: @vgoff of course, in ruby you can even execute private methods. Editing my answer to reflect that. However you don't want to access hidden instance variables or private attributes when dealing with an external lib, do you?

Comment: Was hoping you fixed your initalize method to be named what it needs to bee named so that the `.new` method would invoke it when it is called.

Comment: Fair enough.  Though not having the accessor named foo doesn't mean you can't access them.  It just means that you have to use another mechanism.  I guess my only issue is the comment containing "can't access it" when it is misleading.  You simply can't call A.new.foo and expect to not get the error.

Comment: @vgoff agreed with you :-)